# IE 7/8 mediaelement.js JS console errors, cannot get Flash fallback to work

Tags: mediaelement.js

I know there are a few Flash fallback threads, but I'm sort of having a hard time knowing where to focus my energy here in debugging this problem, your insight would be appreciated!

The SWF is being loaded according to my server logs, I'm seeing playback controls, but in IE 7/8 I'm getting "unspecified error" JS error messages output to console when I press the play button. Therefore the controls do not work, and the line number cited in this console output is pointing to an error with the following statement:

```
this.pluginApi.playMedia();
```

I'm assuming this is calling the Actionscript in the SWF?

What may complicate this is that I'm using this on a WP multisite install, so I'd like to know if the SWF supports cross domain requests (although I've tried calling it from the same domain to no avail), and whether it will work with https (I've tried it without also to no avail). I'm not sure either of these factors are relevant (although it would be nice to know if they are), but given that I've tried replacing the WordPress 2.9.1 JS file with the latest 2.10.1 file and I'm still having the same problem, I'm kind of at a loss to figure out why the Flash fallback is simply not working for me given all that I have tried.

Any debugging recommendations? Is there a version of Mediaelement that is confirmed to work with the Flash fallback?

Thanks in advance for your help here, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the SWF does support cross domain requests
See line 94 of FlashMediaElement.as
It also works with https. I am currently running my own in such an environment.
I hope I could atleast help you in ruling those out.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this much! Do you have any suggestions for what I can try to help get around the javascript error I'm getting which prevents Flash from working? It seems to me like my browser is unable to communicate with Flash/Actionscript?